# New 4tb hard drive can't be accessed

Tags: windows-8, hard-drive

My setup

1. Windows 8.1 64 bit
2. Motherboard ASUS H87I-PLUS
3. The drive is Seagate ST4000DM000 4TB (bought from amazon)

I have installed the SeagateDisc Wizard

It is attached to the motherboard, with SATA and power

It doesn't appear in windows, when i used "Disk Management", the disk appears, and has 3.98TB size, but I get an error ("the request could not be completed because of an i/o device error") when I try to write GPT or MBR to it.

Seagate Disk wizard barely detects it, and corrupted my MBR when I tried to fix it

I booted using a USB Ubunutu and tried GParted, that also failed, GParted could see the drive and the correct size, but couldn't write GPT or MBR

I also bought a USB 3.0 cradle for it to plug in that way, no difference from via SATA. I've plugged it directly and via USB into a second computer with the same results.

What else should I try? Is this disk faulty?

Comment: "but I get an error when I try to write GPT or MBR to it."  What's the error you get? (edit it into your question)  As for what to do next, test it in another computer.

Comment: Have you tried running [the manufacturer's diagnostic tool](http://www.seagate.com/support/downloads/seatools/)?

Comment: I think it's defective, I returned it and a new WD hard drive worked instantly

Comment: The diagnostic tool was extremely slow, it seemed like the SATA interface wasn't working, I tried to repair it but no joy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

" I've plugged it directly and via USB into a second computer with the same results."

If the disk won`t work on another machine, the disk may have been corrupted.